# UIColor: Is grayscale value a property?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/blackColor

> Creating a UIColor with Preset Component Values
>
> ```
> + blackColor
> ```
>
> Returns a color object whose grayscale value is 0.0 and whose alpha
>   value is 1.0.

Is there a method to retrieve a color objects "grayscale value"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `getWhite(_:alpha:)` method on `UIColor` to effectively get the grayscale values.

Playground example:

```
import UIKit

let piColor = UIColor(red: 0.31, green: 0.41, blue: 0.59, alpha: 1.0)
var grayscale: CGFloat = 0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0

if piColor.getWhite(&grayscale, alpha: &alpha) {
    grayscale
    let grayscaleColor = UIColor(white: grayscale, alpha: alpha)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you check the return value of `getWhite`. It may fail if the color spaces aren't compatible.

Comment: BTW - why is orange showing with an RGB of 1, 0, 0? That's red, not orange.

Comment: @rmaddy There are definitely some playground bugs.  Notice here with the new screenshot that the inline preview and the right sidebar show different things in the case of both colors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In case the `effectively` qualifier threw anyone else off, `getWhite` does return the grayscale value according to the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621927-getwhite

Comment: `grayscale` above the `grayscaleColor` declaration appears to be a typo?

Comment: No.  It's just an example for a playground.